# how can I get the content surrounted by <span> tags via xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, import, google-sheets, xpath-2.0

I am trying to get the price from a webpage via Google Spreadsheets via importXML but I can't figure it out. I am not a programmer and have just a basic HTML knowledge. Here is the code:

```
...
<span class="exvat-price"><span class="price"><span class="price">385,76 €</span></span></span><br/>
...
```

I would like to get the result like this:
385,76

I can't narrow my path just into this price and the code returns more prices located on the web (price without VAT, price with VAT,...). I would like to know just this price without VAT.

I hope I explained what I need, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have to start with span containing attribute class with value "extvat-price":
Try:

```
"//span[@class='exvat-price']/span[@class='price']/span[@class='price']/text()"
```